# How to use aps.cer file for APN (Push notification) with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications, node-apn

I'm having issues with node.js sending push notifications, I think because I'm doing something wrong with my APN certificate thats generated in my apple developer account. Im getting this error from Node.js.

```
VError: Failed to generate token: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

I'm not sure I've generated the right file in the apple developer account. See below screenshot, when i click download this gives me a "aps.cer" file which is what i'm putting in my node.js project and using with node-app module. Here is how im setting it in my code:

```
let options = {
        token: {
            key: "aps.cer",
            keyId: "singlemeout.Single-Me-Out",
            teamId: "Team Name"
        },
        production: false
    };
```

Here is a screen shot of my certificate.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing `node-apn` with a token-based configuration, while you are using certificates.

If you want to keep using certificates:

- the certificate should be in PEM format.

  You can do the conversion like this:

  ```
  openssl x509 -inform DER -in aps.cer -out certificate.pem
  ```
- you need to provide the key, either by adding it to the certificate, or by providing it as a separate file
- you need to use the `cert`, `key` and or `pfx` properties in your config object rather than `token.key` etc.

  ```
  let options = {
          cert: "certificate.pem",
          key: "privatekey.pem"
      };
  ```

Alternatively, you can switch to using tokens.

See https://github.com/node-apn/node-apn/blob/master/doc/provider.markdown for full details.

Also your `production` property is not consistent with the certificate used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have a couple questions; What file do i use for the "key" file, is that the original aps.cer file that i have? Or a different file? 
        
Also, after i generate the "certificate.pem" file, how would i define the options variable in my node code? Something like this?
            
       let options = {
        token: {
            keyId: "singlemeout.Single-Me-Out",
            teamId: "Team Name"
        },
        cert: "certificate.pem",
        production: true
    };

Comment: The private key you generated at the same time as the certificate request you uploaded to get your certificate. I don't use the standard Apple procedure and generate it using openssl, but it should be in your Keychain and you will need to export it. I have updated the answer to be more explicit regarding how you should specify the cert and key filenames.

Comment: OK, I found the Apple Push Services certificate in my keychain, which I exported as a .pem into my project directory, but now i get this error when in run node.  Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Comment: I actually looked at both files, and the file in my key chain is identical to the certificate.pem file (this is the .cer that i converted to the .pem using openssl).

Comment: It's not the certificate you need to export, it's the private key. Or both at the same time.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but how do i do that?  I only see  Apple Push Services certificate in my keychain, and when I try export this, there are 3 options:  .cer, .pem, or certificate bundle .p7b.  Do you mean the p7b file, and once i have that how do i extract the private key from it?

Comment: I never use Keychain access for that, but I believe it should be in the "login" keychain (top left), in the "Keys" Category (bottom left). Select it, right-click for export. You probably need to export is as .p12 and then convert it.

Comment: Ah found it. Thanks!  Yes, it was a .12 and i converted it to a .pem and its working.